# Registrar Usuário, Data de Acesso e Tabelas Consultadas no banco de dados PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql

Boa tarde pessoal. Conheço muito pouco do PostgreSql e chegou a seguinte demanda pra mim:

Preciso basicamente de registrar em uma tabela (dentro do próprio banco Postgresql) o usuário que acesso, Data/hora do acesso, qual tabela ele estará consultando os dados e data/hora que ele saiu do banco.

Já pesquisei nos métodos do pg_stat e não encontrei nada.

Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Existem algumas ferramentas que te auxiliam nesta tarefa. Por exemplo o pgAudit. Não vou colocar o link pois senão o moderador apaga meu comentário. Pesquise na internet.

Comment: Dependendo do que deseja dê uma olhada no manual, capítulo Server Configuration / Error Reporting and Logging, que ele mostra como logar as informações de que necessita no formato csv e depois carregar tais dados em uma tabela do BD. Pode ser que atenda a suas necessidades.

Answer (score 1):

você pode criar uma tabela de log_acao com os seguintes campos:
  schema TEXT
  tabela TEXT
  usuario TEXT
  datahora_acao TIMESTAMP 
  acao TEXT 
  dado_original TEXT
  dado_novo TEXT
  consulta TEXT
e depois você pode criar uma função para cada ação:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnc_log_acao_trg (
)
RETURNS trigger AS
$body$
DECLARE
  --
  v_old_data TEXT;
  v_new_data TEXT;
  --
BEGIN
  --
  -- Grava todo e qualquer tipo de ação executada nas tabelas vinculadas a esta função
  IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
    --
    v_old_data := ROW(OLD.*);
    v_new_data := ROW(NEW.*);
    --
    INSERT INTO tbl_log_acao
           (schema
           ,tabela
           ,nome_usuario
           ,datahora_acao
           ,acao
           ,dado_original
           ,dado_novo
           ,consulta
           )
    VALUES (TG_TABLE_SCHEMA::TEXT
           ,TG_TABLE_NAME::TEXT
           ,session_user::TEXT
           ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
           ,substring(TG_OP,1,1)
           ,v_old_data
           ,v_new_data
           ,current_query()
           );
    --
    RETURN NEW;
    --
  ELSIF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
    --
    v_old_data := ROW(OLD.*);
    --
    INSERT INTO tbl_log_acao
           (schema
           ,tabela
           ,nome_usuario
           ,datahora_acao
           ,acao
           ,dado_original
           ,dado_novo
           ,consulta
           )
    VALUES (TG_TABLE_SCHEMA::TEXT
           ,TG_TABLE_NAME::TEXT
           ,session_user::TEXT
           ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
           ,substring(TG_OP,1,1)
           ,v_old_data
           , current_query()
           );
    --
    RETURN OLD;
    --
  ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
    --
    v_new_data := ROW(NEW.*);
    --
    INSERT INTO tbl_log_acao
           (schema
           ,tabela
           ,nome_usuario
           ,datahora_acao
           ,acao
           ,dado_original
           ,dado_novo
           ,consulta
           )
    VALUES (TG_TABLE_SCHEMA::TEXT
           ,TG_TABLE_NAME::TEXT
           ,session_user::TEXT
           ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
           ,substring(TG_OP,1,1)
           ,v_new_data
           ,current_query()
           );
    --
    RETURN NEW;
    --
  ELSE
    --
    RAISE WARNING '[fnc_log_acao_trg] - Outra ação ocorreu: %, no %',TG_OP,now();
    RETURN NULL;
    --
  END IF;
  --
  -- Mantem apenas os últimos 60 dias gravados em banco --
  delete from tbl_log_acao
  where  datahora_acao < (CURRENT_DATE - 60);
  --
EXCEPTION
  WHEN data_exception THEN
    --
    RAISE WARNING '[fnc_log_acao_trg] - UDF ERROR [DATA EXCEPTION] - SQLSTATE: %, SQLERRM: %',SQLSTATE,SQLERRM;
    RETURN NULL;
    --
  WHEN unique_violation THEN
    --
    RAISE WARNING '[fnc_log_acao_trg] - UDF ERROR [UNIQUE] - SQLSTATE: %, SQLERRM: %',SQLSTATE,SQLERRM;
    RETURN NULL;
    --
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    --
    RAISE WARNING '[fnc_log_acao_trg] - UDF ERROR [OTHER] - SQLSTATE: %, SQLERRM: %',SQLSTATE,SQLERRM;
    RETURN NULL;
    --
  --
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql;
```

e para finalizar, pode rodar a trigger de ação nas tabelas

```
CREATE TRIGGER tga_monitor
       AFTER INSERT
          OR UPDATE
          OR DELETE
          ON tbl_monitor
         FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE fnc_log_acao_trg();
```

Comment: Se quer logar os SELECTs também. Mas o perguntador sumiu.